# How can I exclude an element from mousedown

Tags: jquery

I have a Context menu, that should be closed by clicking anywhere in the HTML-DOM:

[image: My Context Menu]

My Problem: A Click on the Link `Make Action` in my Context Menu can not be executed. The context-Menu will be removed before. Here is my Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('html').not(".contextMenu").on('mousedown', function () {

        // remove context menu
        $('.contextMenu').remove();
    });

    $('.contextMenu a').click( function() {
        alert('action');
        $('.contextMenu').remove();
    });   
});
```

jQuery´s `.not()` -Function seems not to work here. I also tried `:not(.contextMenu)` via Sizzle with no success. I used `mousedown`, because Right-Click should remove the Context-Menu, too.

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Y5Fz/1/

Comment: `$(':not(.contextMenu)')` will work in that it won't assign the handler to your context menu. It will however still be assigned to and executed by the parent element of the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

The `.not` is useless, the standard solution is to prevent propagation. You can do this :

```
$('html').on('mousedown', function () {
    // remove context menu
    alert('NO action');
    $('.contextMenu').remove();
});

$('.contextMenu a').click( function() {
    alert('action');
    $('.contextMenu').remove();
    return false; // avoids propagation and so prevents the click on "html"
}).on('mousedown', function(){
    return false; // avoids propagation and so prevents the mousedown on "html"
}) ;
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/xHM6R/)

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. But I need mousedown, because right-click should be possible, too.

Comment: Then also bind mousedown on the a element.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan The goal here is more to prevent propagation rather than the default behavior. And as a `a` element is used and there's an action programmed, `return false` seems to be more useful.

Comment: @dystroy duhh, of course. I want to write `stopPropagation` instead. Muscle memory :)

Comment: Whether `stopPropagation` or return false should be used depends on how is used the link, in fact. We don't have enough information in the question.

Comment: Isn't `return false` the same when you would call both `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` in the event handler?

Comment: @nkmol Yes it is. And most often it's what you want. It stops any additional handling of the event.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('mousedown', function()
    {
        $('.contextMenu').hide();
    })

    $('.contextMenu').on('mousedown', function(e)
    {
        e.stopPropagation();          
    })
});
```

What happens is that you'll remove the `.contextMenu` when clicked anywhere in the document. However, when you click on the `.contextMenu` itself it will cancel the first function that was triggered. 
 Note that i use .hide() as .remove() removes it out of the DOM, but depends if you want to show the `.contextMenu` again.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Y5Fz/8/)**

**Edit**

 Added support of both mouse clicks based on the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document` instead of `html`.Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', function () {
```

**Demo:**http://jsfiddle.net/9Y5Fz/4/

Answer (score 0):

***[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IcAVEHa/1/edit)***

```
$(function() {

    var contMenu_Hovered = 0;

    $(document).on('click', ':not(.contextMenu)', function() {
        if(!contMenu_Hovered) $('.contextMenu').remove();
    });

    $('.contextMenu').hover(function(){
        contMenu_Hovered ^= 1;           // toggle flag 1, 0
    }).on('click', 'a', function() {
        alert('action');
    }); 

});
```

**You need only one `.remove()`**

The clicks that you make on `.contextMenu` propagate to `document`,
but if we set a *flag* `contMenu_Hovered` (`1 for mouseenter, 0 for mouseleave`)
we can use it as `boolean` to test if:

> *while a click was propagated to Document, was the `.contextMenu` hovered?*